# How do I concatenate a boolean to a string in Python?

Tags: python, string, casting, boolean, concatenation

I want to accomplish the following

```
answer = True
myvar = "the answer is " + answer
```

and have myvar's value be "the answer is True". I'm pretty sure you can do this in Java.

Comment: fyi: bools are capitalized in Python (True, False)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The recommended way is to let `str.format` handle the casting ([docs](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings)).  Methods with `%s` substitution may be deprecated eventually (see [PEP3101](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/)).

```
>>> answer = True
>>> myvar = "the answer is {}".format(answer)
>>> print(myvar)
the answer is True
```

In Python 3.6+ you may use [literal string interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/):

```
 >>> print(f"the answer is {answer}")
the answer is True
```

Answer (score 141):

```
answer = True
myvar = "the answer is " + str(answer)
```

Python does not do implicit casting, as implicit casting can mask critical logic errors.  Just cast answer to a string itself to get its string representation ("True"), or use string formatting like so:

```
myvar = "the answer is %s" % answer
```

Note that answer must be set to `True` (capitalization is important).

Answer (score 9):

```
answer = True
myvar = "the answer is " + str(answer)
```

or

```
myvar = "the answer is %s" % answer
```

Comment: The `%s` outside of quotes shouldn't be there, but this is indeed correct.

Answer (score 3):

Using the so called f strings:

```
answer = True
myvar = f"the answer is {answer}"
```

Then if I do

```
print(myvar)
```

I will get:

```
the answer is True
```

I like f strings because one does not have to worry about the order in which the variables will appear in the printed text, which helps in case one has multiple variables to be printed as strings.

Answer (score 0):

answer = True

myvar = 'the answer is ' + str(answer) #since answer variable is in boolean format, therefore, we have to convert boolean into string format which can be easily done using this

print(myvar)

Comment: Welcome to SO, Lijin G. Varghese! Code-only answers are discouraged here, as they provide no insight into how the problem was solved. Please update your answer with an explanation of how your code solves the problem at hand :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want JSON boolean instead of python bool, you can use json module,

```
print(json.dumps(True))
```

Answer (score -2):

```py
answer = “True”

myvars = “the answer is” + answer

print(myvars)
```

That should give you the answer is True easily as you have stored answer as a string by using the quotation marks

Comment: But he doesn't have the answer stored as a string.  It is a boolean.  The question is how to convert a dynamic boolean to its string representation.