# String and True / False

Tags: python

```
def check_guess(letter, guess):
    if letter == guess:
        result = "You are correct"
    elif letter < guess:
        result = "It is too low" + letter == guess
    elif letter > guess:
        result = "It is too high" + letter == guess        
    else:
        result = "It is an invalid input " + letter == guess
    return result

print (check_guess(raw_input("What is your guess (lower case) ?"), raw_input("Please input one lower case alpha! ")))
```

I would like to know why I can't show the string like "It is too low" in the solution?

Comment: Please put the code in the main post.

Answer (score 0):

Your string addition with boolean result is causing the problem. 
try

```
result = "It is too low" + str(letter == guess)
```

and this should do the trick. Also yes as others pointed out, post the code in your question, not just picture.

Better solution can be :

```
result = "It is too low %s" %(letter == guess)
```

[Check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10509803/how-do-i-concatenate-a-boolean-to-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify what you want to display so either as hadi k stated in their answer:

```
result = "It is too low %s" %(letter == guess)
```

gives

"It is too low false"

or

```
result = "It is too low {} == {}".format(letter, guess)
```

gives

"It is too low a == b"

if letter = 'a' and guess = 'b'

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary to check if `letter` equals `guess` in your `if` statements? If not, you can just return the string instead. Hope you get the idea.

```
def check_guess(letter, guess):
    if letter < guess:
        return 'It is too low'

print(check_guess('a', 'b'))
```